# I can't plug in my charger to my Samsung Galaxy tab 3 I think something is broken but i don't know how it happened

Tags: charging, samsung-galaxy-tab-3-7

I really need help because I have no money to buy a new one. I was charging my tablet before a party and when I had to leave I unplugged it came home and it wouldn't plug in and I have tried all kinds of chargers with a micro USB but none of them work [image]

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please define "none of them work": cant they be plugged into the device (physically), as your picture seems to indicate (plug not fully fitting)? In this case, have you checked if something sticks in the hole to prevent that? – Or does the device simply not charge? In which case, have you tried turning off the device and see whether it charges then? Have you only tried USB cables connected to some computer, or also AC wall chargers?

Comment: Can u give us more details?

Answer (score 0):

If the screen shows the status "Charging" but it's stuck, Try the following:

- Reboot your phone.
- Change your battery.
- [Perform Reset Factory](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2458403/how-to-perform-a-factory-reset-on-your-android-phone-or-tablet.html)(Not recommended)

If the device simply not charges:

- See if there's something in the hole(You were at a party, who knows what might be in there!)
- Go to a shop and fix your phone.